# Is the Yearling badge meant to replace the Beta badge?

Tags: support, badges

I have just been awarded the Yearling badge on SO, but have noticed that now my Beta badge has disappeared from my listed badges.  The summary at the top of the page shows 2 silver and 8 bronze, but the list on my details page says 1 silver and 8 bronze.  Perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeff had a change of heart about who could get a Beta badge. If yours was stitched on, but you really only signed up during the beta period and didn't actually participate until it was open, then your Beta badge has been revoked.

Sounds fair seeing as "**actively participated in the private beta**" doesn't match with just signing up and waiting around.

But yeah, that counter at the top is still showing the count with that Beta badge in, like the little piece of skin left after ripping the scab off. Or when you take off a poster from the wall and see that it's a different shade to the rest.

Comment: AFAIK, badges have never been revoked, at least not on a massive scale like this. This is pretty big.

Comment: Jeff mentioned taking them back in the question about all the Beta badges for SO disappearing at the same time they were flooding SU.

Comment: I just rocked over to SuperUser and found that I have been given the Beta badge there.  I don't think I have participated in that site anymore than I did at SO during its Beta.  Asked a question, gave a handful of answers.  Couldn't even vote for most of it - they had a higher threshold in those days ;-)

Comment: Asking/answering a question sounds like active participation compared to some who may have signed up, but never gotten around to answering before the end of beta.

Comment: I _was_ active during the beta, and yet my badge got pulled. (In fact, I was more active then than I am now.)

Comment: Beta ended when the site went public, which was about 15 September 2008. Activity before that release date would have counted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've been affected by this very same issue - I definitely used to have the beta badge on SO.

Comment: Wow, pretty lame.

Comment: It'd be nice if there were some quantitative answer to this as opposed to just "actively participated".

Comment: Participation was defined as earning 3 bronze badges during the beta:

(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18731/why-have-i-lost-my-beta-badge-for-stack-overflow)