# Cancelling downvote didn't cancel Critic badge

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Critic badge badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely)

I currently have the Critic badge, but no downvotes.  I was immediately awarded the badge upon clicking the down arrow, even though I canceled before the downvote was made permanent.

Expected behavior:
The badge should be awarded when the downvote becomes un-undoable, not before.

The [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely) question is tagged "by design" but this behavior has resulted in an inconsistent state — namely, I have a badge without the prereqs.

Comment: You're right, but it's already beaten to death in your dupe link. Badges are almost never revoked. Jeff doesn't care about these tiny inconsistencies. He's not a real programmer, you know...

Comment: That has happened to me

Comment: @LadybugKiller Considering your comment is 11 years old, I wonder if Jeff has ever stumbled upon this somehow.

Answer (score 5):

By design, awarded badges are not removed due to further user actions except for the following exception:

1. Tag badges are removed if the tag score falls below the required threshold.
2. After accounts merge the criteria for most badges is re-calculated (e.g. for Nice Question) and if the merged account doesn't meet the requirements the badge is not passed.

Comment: Not true. Beta badge was removed.

Comment: @John Smithers I still have my Beta badge, when were they removed?

Comment: @dlamblin: Not all were removed, but some. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18731/why-have-i-lost-my-beta-badge-for-stack-overflow

Comment: @John but that was just an exception to the rule, due to a change in the badge requisites. It would be equivalent to creating a new badge with a different name and eliminating the old one. The situation the OP described is different: it's only his actions and status that changed, not any design. He *was* a critic once, and, on SO, once a critic, always a critic.

Comment: @Daniel: I know this pretty well (as you can see by my comment to the question). So what do you want to tell me?

Comment: @John: That "By design, awarded badges are never removed" is still true, or true-ish. A "truer" statement would be "By design, awarded badges are never removed due to further user actions." Removing badges due to the fact that a badge was substantially redefined falls into a different category of actions.

Comment: @Daniel: I do not want to know how you define *false* ;)

Comment: #define false 0 :-)

Comment: Nice I did that?