# Do badges go away?

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Cancelling downvote didn’t cancel Critic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/cancelling-downvote-didnt-cancel-critic-badge)
>   [Is the Critic badge badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely)

I took back my first and only down vote on SO after some clarification to an answer.  Shouldn't my Critic badge go away?

Comment: No. Badges are not revoked.

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854

Comment: FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work-in-stackoverflow