# Reversing serial upvoting should revoke mortarboard badge if was received for those votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, serial-voting, daily-reputation-badges

I noticed this pattern on this user's reputation page:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870173/arju?tab=reputation

It seems it should.  This seems sufficiently poorly designed posting this as a bug.

Comment: FYI - the badge was revoked.

Comment: @Oded must that have been manually?

Comment: The risk of false positives is too great and the occurrence is so rare that it really should be.