# Award Mortarboard and like-badges after serial voting check

Tags: feature-request, badges, serial-voting

Today, all of a sudden, I noticed my rep climbing:

[image: rep]

Now I figured this was going to be reversed soon but then I noticed I got the Mortarboard badge for having hit the rep cap. I figured that the user must have been clever with the serial voting and got around the auto-detection script.

After a couple of hours when I went to check, I got the "Voting corrected" item in the list, but I still have Mortarboard.

After reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126362/250962), I understand why I still have the badge. I would suggest that this badge (and any badge that requires votes that can be gained from serial voting) shouldn't get awarded until after the serial voting check has been done. This way, getting the badge feels more rewarding because you know that people have honestly up-voted your useful posts.

Comment: Sometimes the script doesn't trigger an adjustment for days or weeks after the serial voting starts.  It would be nigh on impossible to implement an effective wait algorithm.

Comment: @Chenmunka: How often does that happen, and how often is it just correcting votes made the previous day? I'd say it's probably at least 95% of the time fixing recent votes, so it should be totally fine to accept a 5% chance of being no better than the current system for a 95% chance of being better.