# Getting your first badges (but not really)

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Critic badge badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely)

A story and a question...

I pressed the +1 arrow next to an answer on someone else's question before realising it was wrong. So I pressed the -1 arrow, thinking this would cancel out my +1. It didn't, it took one away from the original score, so I pressed up again and then learnt that I had to re-press 'up' to undo it.

No problem, I've learnt about the interface and how to use it during this simple exercise.

The bug/feature/other odd behavious was in fact that I was then awarded the Critic badge (for giving negative feedback). Perhaps it's intentional, but it seems odd to be awarded a badge for something I didn't commit to do (it was undone less than a second later). Can users gain all their badges by clicking things once and then undoing them?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/cancelling-downvote-didnt-cancel-critic-badge

Comment: it's by design.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for posting a duplicate - I did search first! I must have used different terminology. I'll take a look at the other questions then; also I have accepted what I think provides the best answer to a fairly subjective question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most badges aren't gotten that way, this is an edge case in that you can undo it.  If you're worried about getting the badge "unfairly", don't be.  It's only a one-time-awarded badge, though [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/) users are happy to not have it...

The interface has been discussed before on Meta, I won't repeat it.  Suffice it to say it makes sense to some people but not others.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing early on with an edit and got a badge.  Emailed the team about it and it was pretty much "Yeah, that'll happen from time to time".

I was cool with that.  In the vast majority of these cases (if not all) the badge would have come soon after the error anyway.  Not a big deal.