# Number of badges in top bar does not match number of badges on account page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

In the top bar (on StackOverflow), after my account name, it says I have 3 silver badges and 5 bronze badges. But when I want to find out which badges I have on my user page, I see only 2 silver badges and 5 bronze badges.

So there is a discrepancy, and I have no idea why!

Comment: Closed as 'bydesign' because you filed it as a bug.  It seems like there might be a feature request in there somewhere to change the design to something the adjusts badge counts right away, but that's really a different issue.

Comment: I filed it as a bug because I saw different numbers for the same thing. Now I know more about the issue, and in my opinion the badge totals should be recalculated when you lose a badge.

Comment: I by mistake, up-voted your preceding comment and now I can't undo it. Maybe "bydesign". ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The badge is a lie.

More to the point, you at one time had the Beta badge and in total would count as a silver badge.

After the [revocation of the Beta badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15582/is-the-yearling-badge-meant-to-replace-the-beta-badge), it still left the remnant count of an extra silver badge up top.

For the record, while you may have signed up before the end of Beta, if you didn't notch up three (3) bronze badges before the end, you do not qualify.

[image: too bad, so sad]

It's like a scar really.

Comment: That's the reason the numbers don't match. Maybe all badge totals should have been recalculated after revoking the Beta badges.

Answer (score 4):

Badge totals aren't recalculated if you lose a badge. The next time you earn a badge that you've lost (either a specific badge or a type of badge) the total won't increment.

Reasons why you might have lost a badge:

1. The Beta badge criteria were changed retrospectively and there was a reassignment.
2. A question might have been migrated to another site - where you will earn the badges (but not the rep - until a recalc is done) straight away.
3. The OP might change the accepted answer from your 10+ vote answer to another, hence losing you the Enlightened badge.

Comment: This type of thing would happen to me a lot in the past where I would have Nice and Good answer badges disappearing all the time and it took me a while to figure it out myself.