# WebMasters.SE Inconsistent Badge Count - No Badges Lost

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I earned (or at least should have and seem to partially have been awarded) the Enthusiast badge on WebMasters. [(Profile)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/46/rchern)

[image: Profile Badges]

[image: Banner Badges]

I have read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22143/number-of-badges-in-top-bar-does-not-match-number-of-badges-on-account-page) and more specifically, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22143/number-of-badges-in-top-bar-does-not-match-number-of-badges-on-account-page/22145#22145) but I don't think it is the same thing.  From what I can tell, I haven't lost any of the silver badges.  I checked the [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-to-make-a-printer-friendly-version-of-a-webpage/865#865) I earned the Enlightened badge for, and it is still the accepted answer and has 17 votes.

I have cleared my cache, refreshed, logged in from a computer that had never accessed WebMasters from, and I see the same thing.

Edit:  The situation is the same on [Meta.WebMasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46/rchern) in that it shows I have 0 silver badges, but also shows I've earned Enthusiast.

---

**UPDATE:**  This seems to be a larger issue.  I went with the wait-and-see tactic with the cooking site.  The enthusiast badge was awarded with my 30th consecutive day.  Since then, I've seen 0 silver badges at the top when I login, but at the bottom of my profile, I see the Enthusiast badge.  I'm now at 43 days consecutive.  On the cooking meta, I don't see the Enthusiast badge in either spot, so not sure about there.

Comment: The enthusiast badge has always been [too enthusiast](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Benthusiast+%2Bbadge+%5Bbug%5D).

Comment: @rchern is one of several who received the badge today, but the only one experiencing this problem.

Comment: @BalusC, per my profile:  *visited 30 days, 30 consecutive*

Comment: Badge summary updated.

Comment: @Kevin, on the parent site, yup.  Thanks.  Is it just a wait kind of thing?  I'll check meta tomorrow.  What was so special about this particular badge/site combo that got messed up?

Comment: @rchern - Not sure yet what caused the de-sync, it should fix itself with time in theory, though in your particular case I just hit a handy "resync" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your badge count will be updated when you get another badge. Apparently the Enthusiast badge doesn't recalculate the badge count.

I had the same issue as you, and the badge count was corrected when I earned a bronze badge.

Comment: Hmm, really?  SO, MSO, and WA adjusted the counts I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @rchern It took me a week to get my Enthusiast badge display in my badge count and it got display at the same exact moment I got the Organizer badge.

Comment: While I'm 99% sure the others have been correct, I've been awarded badges since so can't prove it.  Howeven, on SO, I haven't been awarded a badge since the Enthusiast but my [count](http://stackoverflow.com/users/181481?tab=activity#tab-top) is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just hang tight for a little while.  Many stat things are served out of caches.  Eventually they'll catch up and the totals will match.

Comment: Just thought it was weird because I haven't had a problem with any other badges and I never got the notification bar telling me I had a new badge.

Comment: I got the same badge on the same site, and my totals match. So strange :)