# Badge count at the top is wrong

Tags: support, badges

Yes, this isn't the first question about this, but since [this one is already answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/wrong-badge-count), I'm asking a new question.

Two days ago I got a badge on SO for `Popular Question`. That badge appeared at the bottom of my profile, but wasn't counted at the top. Therefore, I know have 15 bronze badges at the top and 16 at the bottom. According to [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/wrong-badge-count/72260#72260) the count should be correct after maximum 24 hours.

Well, it's not.

I know how to update the reputation counter, but that didn't update the badge counters. Furthermore, note that I haven't lost any badges.

To me this sounds like a bug. If it's "by design" as I read it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22143/number-of-badges-in-top-bar-does-not-match-number-of-badges-on-account-page) then please add some functionality to recalculate it.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I was about to ask the same one. Your question popped up in suggested ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483113/sjngm), you have 15 bronze and 1 silver badge. So the 15 is correct.

Comment: oh my... After two cups of coffee I noticed that 15+1=16 \*sigh* Maybe I should go home and get some sleep...

Comment: @sjngm, great idea.  And we all have those moments.